# PHP - преобразование запроса в PDO

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Как преобразовать такой SELECT в PDO?

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND activation='1'",$db);
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
if (empty($myrow2['id']))
   {
   //Если не действительны (может мы удалили этого пользователя из базы за плохое поведение)
    exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!");
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=:email AND password=:password AND activation='1'";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindParam( ":email", $_SESSION['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ":password", $_SESSION['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );                 
if (empty($result['id']))
{
   //Если не действительны (может мы удалили этого пользователя из базы за плохое поведение)
    exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!");
}
```

Comment: Вместо $this->db подставьте ваш экземпляр PDO

Comment: Типа этого:

    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . Config::DB_HOSTNAME . ";dbname=" . Config::DB_NAME;
    $this->db = new PDO( $dsn, Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASSWORD );